# How to see definitions in Visual Studio for files installed using vcpkg?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

I'm using [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) library manager and with it I've installed gtk.

In VS2019 I have included `#include "gtk/gtk.h"` and when I `Ctrl+Click` on that line I end-up in that header file. Then I go to `#include <gtk/gtkmain.h>` and in there we see a bunch of interesting functions, for example `gtk_init_abi_check`. But this is only a declaration and I would like to see implementations (definitions) of these functions. `RightMouseClick -> Go to declaration` on function's name doesn't do anything.

Can I even use vcpkg for getting the libraries but also the code that I can read?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to add `gtk` projects to your main Visual studio solution :

1. Download and extract [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)
2. Add all vcpkg projects

[image]

3. Search `vcxproj` in `toolsrc` present in the extracted folder (step 1)

   [image]
4. Do same thing for `vcpkg, vcpkglib` and `vcpkgtest` if you want test project
   [image]
5. Thea goal is to integrate `gtk` projects to your solution:

[image]

6. Now, you can use `go to implementation`

**Remarque** : If your main VS solution has a different version from the downloaded librarie, use Cmake to generate a new `vcpkg, vcpkglib` and `vcpkgtest` projects and do the same thing